# SQL Select only Items where AVG bigger than

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have two Tables Recipes and Ratings. I only want to get Recipes where the AVG of stars in Ratings is higher than 4 (Stars). Database is MySQL

Structure:

Recipes
- id
- title
- teaser
- description

Ratings
- id
- recipeid (id from Recipes)
- stars

Can Somebody helps me with the Query ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? And where **specifically** are you stuck? We're not a code-writing service; please see [ask].

Comment: What queries have you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put that condition in the `having` clause:

```
select     recipes.*
from       recipes
inner join ratings on recipes.id = ratings.recipeid
group by   recipes.id
having     avg(ratings.stars) > 4
```

Comment: SELECT recipes.* .... GROUP BY recipes.id is wrong SQL and will fail on server with sql_mode=only_full_group_by ... read https://www.psce.com/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Comment: @RaymondNijland, I thought this was only so when the other fields are not functionally dependent, but they are functionally dependent in this case. Please correct me if I am wrong. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html

Comment: true your query may show correct results assuming recipes.id is unique.. but your query will fail on Servers with sql_mode set only_full_group_by causing a error.

Comment: But functionally dependent fields are excluded from that restriction: *"**ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY**: Reject queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are neither named in the GROUP BY clause **nor are functionally dependent on (uniquely determined by) GROUP BY columns**."* (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a join (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) and then a group by (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) . These are pretty basic SQL concepts that you need to really learn if you are going to work with the language. The w3schools tutorials are very good.

```
SELECT Recipes.title , AVG(Ratings.stars) as avgRating
FROM Recipes INNER JOIN Ratings ON Recipes.id = Ratings.recipeid
GROUP BY Recipes.title
WHERE AVG(Ratings.stars) > 4
```

Comment: Operator should be > because "I only want to get Recipes where the AVG of stars in Ratings is higher than 4 (Stars)"

Comment: @RaymondNijland yep had just spotted that and edited :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need a combination of [`group by`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) and `having`. This will return the ids and titles of all recipes with an average rating of more than 4 stars:

```
select re.id, re.title, avg(ra.stars)
from Recipes re inner join Ratings ra on re.id = a.recipeid
group by re.id
having avg(ra.stars) > 4;
```

See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/01f648/10/0) for a working demo in 5.6 or [this fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2Bp7S566D87SfmbyrX7rqn/0) for a 5.7 version and [`any_value`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value).

Answer (score 0):

Same logic as below. The key is combine  the group by and having condition.
Which departments have more
than 10 employees?

```
SELECT deptno, COUNT(*) AS "Number of employees"
FROM Employee

GROUP BY deptno HAVING COUNT(*) > 10

ORDER BY deptno
```